# Uncaught ReferenceError: chroma is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, spectrogram

I am creating a spectrogram that on click of a button displays but keeps giving me this error and i do not understand what the problem is if anyone can help i would be very thankful!

```
// used for color distribution
    var myColor = new chroma.ColorScale({
        colors:['#000000', '#ff0000', '#ffff00', '#ffffff'],
        positions:[0, .25, .75, 1],
        mode:'rgb',
        limits:[0, 300]
    });
```

This is the defined variable ^^^

```
function Spectrogram() {
        // Start visualizer.
  requestAnimFrame(drawSpectrogram)
}
```

This is the on button activation ^^^^

```
//draw the spectrogram
    function drawSpectrogramVisualisation() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //store a temp copy of the canvas
    //create a temp canvas we use for copying
    var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    tempCanvas.width = spectrogramCanvasWIDTH;
    tempCanvas.height = spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT
    var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,0,0, spectrogramCanvasWIDTH, spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT);

    var freqDomain = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqDomain);

    if(spectrogramLeftPos == spectrogramCanvasWIDTH){
        for (var i = 0; i< analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++) { 

        var value = freqDomain[i]
        tempCtx.fillStyle = myColor.getColor(value).hex();
        tempCtx.fillRect(spectrogramCanvasWIDTH - 1, (spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT - i), 1, 1);
        }
        context.translate(-1, 0);
        context.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0, spectrogramCanvasWIDTH, spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT);
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < analyser.frequencyBinCount; i++) {
                var value = freqDomain [i];
                tempCtx.fillStyle = myColor.getColor(value).hex();
                tempCtx.fillRect(spectrogramLeftPos, (spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT - i), 1, 1);
            }

            context.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0, spectrogramCanvasWIDTH, spectrogramCanvasHeight);
            spectrogramLeftPos++;
    }
}
```

This is the spectrogram function ^^^^

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chroma.js"></script>
```

This is in the html section inside the Head tag. ^^

Comment: Are you sure that you have added `chroma.js`?

Comment: if you are referring to the HTML statement it is this
<script type="text/javascript" src="chroma.js"></script>

Comment: @Goodwine that what you meant?

Comment: Are you loading `chroma.js` (with that tag) before or after the JS code? It should be on top of it.

Comment: @MarcoCI i put my code into jsfiddle here how i laid it all out 

http://jsfiddle.net/Yc887/

The chroma file is not on the fiddle though since i did not know how to add in another jscript file but it is there in the same folder with it on my local drive

Comment: Swap the order of import of the JS files: `chroma.js` first, then the other JS file.

Comment: @MarcoCI Yes you were right sorry just got a different error now

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: spectrogramCanvasHeight is not defined

Comment: @user3642553 it seems that your variable is called `spectrogramCanvasHEIGHT`, and you wrote `Height` in lowercase.